# Kotlin: print class name without reflection in multiplatform project

Tags: kotlin, reflection

Data classes print out just fine in MPP projects. When I `toString()` the `KClass` object for my class, I get:

```
class com.example.MySimpleClass (Kotlin reflection is not available)
```

How Can I do what data class does and have a nice clean name without reflection?

Comment: Data classes print their class name because their `toString` method is generated during compilation, and their name is inserted by compiler just as a string literal. You can't get a class name from `KClass` object without `kotlin-reflect` library.

Comment: But it literally got the name next to the "Kotlin reflection is not available" string. Why?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have it set up myself to test, so answer is based purely on documentation:

[`KClass.simpleName` is available in Common code](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/simple-name.html); `qualifiedName` isn't, but since 1.3 it is on every platform, so you could define an `expect fun` in your multiplatform part and make all `actual` implementations access `qualifiedName`.

Comment: I executed it, it's not available.

Comment: Does it fail to compile or throw an exception? And on which platform if the latter?

Comment: On JVM (in unit test), throws: `class java.lang.Exception (Kotlin reflection is not available)`

Comment: Can you provide a complete example? Looking at https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/74c9120d9dd98db82ae11568fd887edfb88e0133/libraries/stdlib/jvm/runtime/kotlin/jvm/internal/ClassReference.kt, seems like it should work.

Comment: Of course, there is also the hacky option: call `kclassObject.toString().replace("class ", "").replace(" (Kotlin reflection is not available)", "")` :)